# WPF: Why should I use an existing MVVM framework instead of writing my own?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I was wondering what benefits an MVVM framework could give me (such as mvvm light, prism, etc). If you can give me bullet points stating from most important to least important. I'm just trying to understand if I should use an MVVM framework or just hand code my own.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739675/what-wpf-frameworks-should-i-use

Comment: not the same, he's asking what framework to use. not the benefits in using mvvm framework in general

Comment: There are a number of similar questions on SO. i.e., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653096/why-use-mvvm , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644453/why-mvvm-and-what-are-its-core-benefits] , http://www.google.com/search?q=benefits+of+mvvm+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: metro, those are MVVM questions. not the BENEFITS of an MVVM FRAMEWORK Please read my question. thank you.

Comment: It's a correct question. I'm also interesting why some people use frameworks and what the frameworks give that I can't implement using just plain objects?

Comment: This has already been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409553/what-framework-for-mvvm-should-i-use

Comment: Using the MVVM frameworks out there shortcuts the process of developing the pattern. Like you I question the level of benefits these frameworks bring to the table as opposed to writing your own code to accomplish the same thing?  I have not found a MVVM scenario yet that I could not hand code myself.  I am working in UWP, Xamarin Forms, WPF and still have not needed a MVVM framework to accomplish my needs.

Answer (score 5):

You can get started with MVVM without a framework, and you can build up your own base code over time. It might help you learn the pattern better.

Once you understand it, you will better appreciate the power that a framework like [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) gives you. The frameworks get all that base template code out of the way, of course, but they also can add advanced binding, action, and composition features.

I just listened to a podcast interview with the author of Caliburn Micro. Maybe it will help you:

[Herding Code 104: Rob Eisenberg on Caliburn Micro](http://herdingcode.com/?p=303)

Answer (score 1):

mvvm light:

- Messages - simple way to exchange data between windows
- DispatcherHelper - allows to make updating controls from other threads easier
- and other [link](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/)

Comment: thanks but I'm looking for what is general about these frameworks, not just mvvm light. (I am sure all these frameworks overlap somewhere)